# Redirect toUrl does not work (zf2)

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have a problem with a redirect in Zend Framework 2.
when a user enters a url like http//mysite.test/lorem, he will be redirected to http//mysite.test/news/view/lorem-ipsum.

the code:

```
$redirecttable = $sm->get('Redirect\Model\RedirectTable');
$route = $redirecttable->getRedirectByRoute($this->params()->fromRoute('page'));
if($route) {
    // $route->getToroute() returns "news/view/Lorem-Ipsum"
    return $this->redirect()->toUrl( $route->getToroute() );

}
```

Am I making a stupid mistake here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toUrl` method redirect to a complete url, but you're sending part of url. You can use `$this->redirect()->toRoute($route,$params)` for redirecting to a route. [reference](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.0/en/modules/zend.mvc.plugins.html#the-redirect-plugin)

If you want to use `toUrl` method, try this code:

```
return $this->redirect()->toUrl( $this->getRequest()->getUri()->toString().$route->getToroute() );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `toRoute()` instead of `toUrl()`:

`return $this->redirect()->toRoute($route->getToroute())`

Comment: doesn't `toRoute()` need the route specified in the models example: `$this->redirect()->toRoute('news', array('action' => 'view'));`?